# ffmpeg (IMAGE THUMBNAIL 1 frame) how to "choose" compression quality when we use -vframes 1 (how to do like convert -quality 60....)

Tags: ffmpeg

• PRE-CONTEXT : with ImageMagick, I'm use to do `convert -quality 60 1.jpg 1.webp` here "quality 60" affect the final size of the output

• CONTEXT : create a poster.webp OR poster.jpg of a movie.mp4

• QUESTION : how can we "achieve" the same compression level choice with ffmpeg when we want 1 frame

• WHAT I TRIED [1] :

`ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -vframes 1 -qmin 0 -qmax 1  0.webp`

and `ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -vframes 1 -qmin 50 -qmax 51 50.webp`

==>> both gives the exact same size for the output.

• WHAT I TRIED [2] :

`ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -vframes 1 -b:v 9k bv9k.webp`

and `ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -vframes 1 -b:v 1k bv1k.webp`

==>> both gives the exact same size for the output.

what I'm I missing or miss using here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's `-qscale`

`/usr/brew/ffmpeg -i x.mp4 -qscale:v 31 31.webp` ==> BIG SIZE mega quality

`/usr/brew/ffmpeg -i x.mp4 -qscale:v 1 1.webp` ==> small size low quality